# Surface pen keeps jumping to the same spot while drawing but not with a finger or the eraser end

Tags: touchscreen, surface, libinput

I'm using a Surface 3 with a Surface pen (the newest one) to try and draw in Krita. The problem is it believes the pen keeps jumping to the top:

[image: Screenshot that illustrates the problem]

I suspected it was just a problem with the touchscreen, but it only happens with the pen tip: it doesn't happen with a finger or with the eraser end of the pen. I also tested the pen on a Surface Go and it worked perfectly. Now I don't know if it's the Pen or the Surface 3 that's broken.

It happens in both:

- Xournal++ in the standard Ubuntu desktop environment
- Krita in KDE

The output from `sudo libinput debug-events` when this happens is (relevant part is the up/down TABLET_TOOL_TIP events):

```
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.477s              99.65*/89.42*   pressure: 0.43
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.483s              100.65*/89.12*  pressure: 0.43
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.492s              101.53*/89.00*  pressure: 0.43*
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.498s              102.20*/89.02*  pressure: 0.44*
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_TIP  +2.499s              108.05*/1.23*   pressure: 0.00* up
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_TIP  +2.507s              103.20*/89.83*  pressure: 0.44* down
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.513s              103.12*/90.04*  pressure: 0.45*
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.522s              102.95*/90.62*  pressure: 0.45
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.529s              102.70*/91.46*  pressure: 0.45
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.538s              102.15*/92.85*  pressure: 0.45
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.543s              101.35*/94.56*  pressure: 0.45
 event13  TABLET_TOOL_AXIS +2.552s              100.35*/96.44*  pressure: 0.45
```

As this happens close to exactly the same coordinates every time (within the same 0.02mm or so) and the drawing seems to be OK otherwise, I was wondering if there was a way to filter out any libinput events that happen very close to 108.05/1.23 (where I won't be drawing anyway). Alternatively, would it be easier if I just bought a new pen? And if I do, would it be likely to fix the problem?

I also swapped out the pen battery for a new one but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem. In my case the pen kept jumping down. I also tried by hacking the software and buying a new pen, but no help. In the end I called the service (my laptop was still in guarantee), and thy said it was a display problem. And indeed changing the display solved the problem